# How does one grep the Help from admin templatates in Powershell?

Tags: windows, group-policy

If I open my `Local Group Policy Editor` in Windows and go to `Local Computer Policy -> Administrative Templates -> Control Panel -> Personalization` for example, and then I click on one of the many settings listed, is there a way to grep all of the policy descriptions (listed as `Help:`) to find the particular policy I want to look at without reading through all of them, using PowerShell or some other tool?

[image: I want to grep the highlighted text across policies]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the group policy editor, click on "Administrative Templates" (either in Computer Configuration or User Configuration), then:

"Action" -> "Filter Options" -> select "Any" in "Managed", "Configured" and "Commented" to match all the group policies.

Then, you can "Enable keyword filters" and create your filter. The view will be filtered until you uncheck "Action" -> "Filter On".

> [image: Group Policies: Filter Options]

(you'll need to check "Help text" unlike the screenshot above)